# Application login system not working SQL LOCAL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'am doing my program and i need login and register system. My register system is working but login not.

I have done register system

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = ConnectionDb; Integrated Security = True");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From UsersConfig where Email='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and Password='" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "'", sqlCon);
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dtbl);
if (dtbl.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = ConnectionDb; Integrated Security = True");
    SqlDataAdapter sdaa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From UsersConfig where Email='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and Password='" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "' and AdminYes='" + "1" + "'", sqlConn);
    DataTable dtbll = new DataTable();
    sdaa.Fill(dtbll);
    if (dtbll.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Has admin");
        Form adminpanel = new AdminPanel();
        adminpanel.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hasn't got admin");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not working!");
}
```

I don't have error message

Comment: Why you open database twice? You should use one connection with two adapters, depose the first one after done.

Comment: There is no need to use a datatable for this, pass your query to an `SqlCommand` and execute it using `ExecuteScalar` It's ideal for returning a single result from a query. I would also think you could instead just return AdminYes's value and if no row is returned, login was unsuccessful, if a row is returned, you then know if they are admin. Also, while looking up the 2 things I listed, also look at using Parameters for your user input values. And Ideally you should be comparing a password hash instead of storing passwords in plain text in your table.

Comment: Check out the first example on this Microsoft page. It is using stored procedure, but it shows how to use a `using` statement for SqlConnection and how to handle error catching with a `try {} catch {}` for `SqlException` errors. You may have a database connection error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Single quotes are used to indicate a parameter is a string.  AdminYes should be a zero or a one and you have single quotes arount the one which makes it a string.  So you are comparing "1" with 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions from the comments above and the Microsoft link would change the code to be something like this below. Also, using parameters instead of building the string manually is HIGHLY recommended as building the SQL string can lead to SQL injection security vulnerabilities.

NOTE: I do not think this will fix the error you are having, but it may help find the issue.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = ConnectionDb; Integrated Security = True";

using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string email = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    string pwd = textBox2.Text.Trim();

    //NOTE: passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text. 
    //There should be an hashing step here like:
    pwd = MyCustomPasswordHasher(email, pwd);

    string sql = "Select [AdminYes] From UsersConfig where Email=@user and Password=@password";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", email);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pwd);

    try
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials!");
        }
        else if (result.ToString() == "1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Has admin");
            Form adminpanel = new AdminPanel();
            adminpanel.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hasn't got admin");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Database errors!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Navio excellent. Please make sure to make this as the answer. Thanks!